# Radar Search Requests are randomly failing with "status" : "UNKNOWN_ERROR"

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

Here is the url. Replace [KEY] with your key.

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?sensor=true&radius=402&types=accounting|airport|amusement_park|aquarium|art_gallery|bakery|bank|bar|beauty_salon|bicycle_store|book_store|bowling_alley|bus_station|cafe|campground|car_dealer|car_rental|car_repair|car_wash|casino|cemetery|church|city_hall|clothing_store|convenience_store|courthouse|dentist|department_store|doctor|electrician|electronics_store|embassy|establishment|finance|fire_station|florist|food|funeral_home|furniture_store|gas_station|general_contractor|grocery_or_supermarket|gym|hair_care|hardware_store|health|hindu_temple|home_goods_store|hospital|insurance_agency|jewelry_store|laundry|lawyer|library|liquor_store|local_government_office|locksmith|lodging|meal_delivery|meal_takeaway|mosque|movie_rental|movie_theater|moving_company|museum|night_club|painter|park|parking|pet_store|pharmacy|physiotherapist|place_of_worship|plumber|police|post_office|real_estate_agency|restaurant|roofing_contractor|rv_park|school|shoe_store|shopping_mall|spa|stadium|storage|store|subway_station|synagogue|taxi_stand|train_station|travel_agency|university|veterinary_care|zoo&location=37.785834%2C-122.406417&key=[KEY]

When i call this url it will sometimes work but most of the time i get back

```
{
    "html_attributions" : [],
    "results" : [],
    "status" : "UNKNOWN_ERROR"
}
```

Steps:
  paste the url into Chrome (replace [key] with real key) and just reload the url request several time.

Thank you
Frank

Comment: UNKNOWN_ERROR: The PlacesService request could not be processed due to a server error. The request may succeed if you try again.

Answer (score 0):

Google itself seems to have this error:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-radar-search

Click the link and their page throws an error.